# Unity Destroy GameObject instantiated clone

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

There's something I'm trying to achieve which is destroy an instantiated object (which is a Particle System). After doing some research, I found the way to instantiate and destroy the instantiated object is this:

```
public class CoinCollider : MonoBehaviour
{   
    public Transform coinEffect;

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider info)
    {
        if (info.name == "Ball")
        {
            GameObject effect = GameObject.Instantiate(coinEffect, transform.position, transform.rotation) as GameObject;

            Destroy(effect);
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

but it seems not to delete it, this object is inherited to one object which is being destroyed. But after making this destroy. it seems to create another gameObject with name "Particle System(clone)" with no parent. How to delete it?

Comment: What do you mean by "this object is inherited to one object which is being destroyed".

Comment: @FunctionR i meant it has an parent object

Comment: It should be alright. Check my answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Problem

I found your problem and you are a victim of Unity being overprotective. You are trying to destroy the transform component of the clone, but you are not allowed to do that so Unity just ignores you.

### Solution

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider info)
{
   if(info.name == "Ball")
      Destroy(Instantiate(coinEffect.gameObject, transform.position, transform.rotation), 5f);
}
```

So all you only need this one line. You Instantiate the [gameObject](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component-gameObject.html) component of the effect's  [transform](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.html). Then [Destroy](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Destroy.html) it using a timer, I gave it `5f`, or else the effect would be destroyed instantaneously.

Comment: your code was the solution, thank you for that.. how did you know unity does this kind of stuff?

Comment: I have been using Unity for a while now.

Comment: Your solution works. I ran into this trap recently and finally found this. I think this is confusing. If Unity doesn't want us to destroy it immediately it should warn us or throw an exception directly. I checked my code so may times and was upset to found that there was nothing else wrong, I just didn't know it won't be destroyed like that...

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

void DestroyProjectile()
{
Destroy(Instantiate(destroyEffect, transform.position, Quaternion.identity), 3f);